# How to validate length of a variable that is declared through getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want the **length** of the variable pw1 to be compared with the numerical value 5.
I got the variable by **document.getElementById.value**. 
But I think this variable is not a string, so the length method is not working.

```js
//Enter code to display "Password is too short" if the password is less than 5 characters

function PasswordlengthCheck() {
 var pw1 = document.getElementById("Pword1").value;
if(pw1.value.length < 5){ //why is this not working?
document.getElementbyId("Placeholder1").innerHTML="Password too short";
}
else{
document.getElementbyId("Placeholder1").innerHTML="";
}
```

```html
<html> 
<body>
 
<h1>Some password<br>check script</h1>

 <p>Please enter your new password here:<br>
  <input id="Pword1" type="text"  value=""><br>
<p id= "Placeholder1"></p>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error missing a `}`. You fat fingered `getElementbyId`.  You are not calling the method.

Comment: `But I think this variable is not a string` that is not correct. `document.getElementById("Pword1").value` will return a string

Comment: `var pw1 = document.getElementById("Pword1").value;
if(pw1.value.length < 5)` `pw1` is a **value** not an element.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of typos and you were not calling the function. I'm going to assume that's just you pasting the code in your question and not related to your problem.

Your variable `pw1` contained the value and in your if statement you were getting `pw1.value` so it gave you an error since what you were really doing was `document.getElementById("Pword1").value.value.length`. Removed the extra `.value` and to test I added the function `onkeydown` of the input.

Here's the working example:

```js
//Enter code to display "Password is too short" if the password is less than 5 characters
function PasswordlengthCheck() {
  var pw1 = document.getElementById("Pword1").value;
  if (pw1.length < 5) { //why is this not working?
    document.getElementById("Placeholder1").innerHTML = "Password too short";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Placeholder1").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Some password<br>check script</h1>

  <p>Please enter your new password here:<br>
    <input id="Pword1" type="text" value="" onkeydown="PasswordlengthCheck()"><br>
    <p id="Placeholder1"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have quite a few errors in your code,

1. `document.getElementById` (its `ById` not `byId`)
2. Missing function end braces
3. function not called anywhere
4. remove `value` from at least from one of the 2 places (1. `document.getElementById("Pword1")` and 2. `if (pw1.value.length < 5)`)

after resolving everything below working example should work for you!

```js
//Enter code to display "Password is too short" if the password is less than 5 characters

function PasswordlengthCheck() {
  var pw1 = document.getElementById("Pword1");
  console.log(pw1.value.length );
  if (pw1.value.length < 5) { //why is this not working?
    document.getElementById("Placeholder1").innerHTML = "Password too short";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("Placeholder1").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Some password<br>check script</h1>

  <p>Please enter your new password here:<br>
    <input id="Pword1" type="text" value="" oninput="PasswordlengthCheck()"><br>
    <p id="Placeholder1"></p>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you got the value in first place
`var pw1 = document.getElementById("Pword1").value;`
you don't need to get it again by 
`if(pw1.value.length<5){
//....
}`

just remove the value attribute from pw1 and do it like
`if(pw1.length<5){
//....
}`